# txtai.database.sql.base.SQLError: no such function: json_extract

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

Using TxtAI python module with sql query <kbd>SELECT id, text, score, solution_id, column_name FROM txtai WHERE similar('{query}') AND score >= 0.5</kbd>, I am seeing this error <kbd>txtai.database.sql.base.SQLError: no such function: json_extract</kbd>

I am trying to use dynamic search using TxtAI module, which uses a SQL based context manager but it is not working as expected.

This are working perfectly on my widows machine, but the same is not happening on the CentOS server. I have tried to maintain all the modules and packages versions same using requirement.txt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the version of SQLite packaged with CentOS 7.9 doesn't have the JSON1 extension enabled. There may be a 3rd party repository with a newer version.

The link below shows how SQLite could be recompiled with JSON1 enabled.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/JSON1Extension

Alternatively, you can try with another Linux distro. Almost all distros released within the last 5 years have JSON1 support enabled.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) and Python 3.7.13

Comment: Answer updated with additional details.

Comment: if I use Docker in CentOS 7.9 will it work? and, what Linux image would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, using Docker would work. I'd recommend starting with the standard neuml/txtai-cpu image (https://hub.docker.com/r/neuml/txtai-cpu). This uses Ubuntu 20.04 as a base image.

The Dockerfile for neuml/txtai-cpu is available on GitHub: https://github.com/neuml/txtai/blob/master/docker/base/Dockerfile